# Geometric problem about kites maybe

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

The radius of the circle is $20$, is there anyway I can calculate the angle connecting the two radii? I'm supposed to show that it is equal to $\frac \pi{3}$

It is basically supposed to be $7$ pipes stacked to make a hexagon and they're bunched up by tight rope, which makes the tangents here.

Comment: If six pipes are symmetrically arranged about the seventh, then the six points of tangency are symmetrically arranged, so ...

Comment: Any more details? I haven't learned anything about this in my A level course

Comment: You haven't learned to divide by $6$? :)

Comment: AHH FFSS ITS A GOD DAMN HEXAGON. $720/6 = 120$, $180-120=60$ = $1/3π$

I got too immersed in calculus and arithmetic that I forgot 3rd grade geometry

Comment: More simply: From the full central angle $2\pi$, just calculate $2\pi/6 = \pi/3$. ... We all have moments like that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

- the red hexagons and red radii involve a lot of right angles so the red radii come in parallel pairs
- so the six blue angles (equal to each other by symmetry) add up to a circle
- so each blue angle is  $\frac{2\pi}{6}$

[image]

Comment: That's not the best way to solve it though. I am a god damn moron, it's a god damn hexagon, the tangents are symmetrical so its 720/6, then for the rule of cyclic quadrilaterals so 180-120 = 60

Comment: @MajdDia Somehow you need the seven pipes to make a hexagon.  You can choose whether you use the green hexagon or the red hexagon

Comment: @MajdDia Sorry, English not being my mother's language, how would you say in ordinary terms "I am a god damn moron, it's a god damn hexagon" ?

Comment: @Henry Very astute [+1]